# How to click on element within iframe?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, iframe, element, webautomation

I’m trying to do web automation on IE using Selenium library.
Elements I want to click have iframes.

However, I’m getting the “element not found” error.

I tried many different approaches.

```vbs
Sub activeBexIE_Final()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim Perm_bot As New Selenium.IEDriver
    Perm_bot.Get "https://nalcodirect.nalco.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/pcd%213aportal_content%212fcom.sap.pct%212fplatform_add_ons%212fcom.sap.ip.bi%212fiViews%212fcom.sap.ip.bi.bex?BOOKMARK=0O867HQNBT13YLB5Q21HLAL2H", timeout:=1000, Raise:=False

    Perm_bot.Wait 5000

    ' website opening successfully
    Perm_bot.FindElementById("logonuidfield").SendKeys "XYZ@ABC.com"
    Perm_bot.SendKeys Perm_bot.Keys.Tab
    Perm_bot.SendKeys "ABCD"
    Perm_bot.SendKeys Perm_bot.Keys.Enter

    ' the error is element not found at .click line
    Perm_bot.switchToFrame Perm_bot.FindElementByName("iframe_Roundtrip_9223372036563636042")
    Perm_bot.FindElementById("BUTTON_OPEN_SAVE_btn1_acButton").Click

    Perm_bot.Wait 5000

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    perm_dot.Quit
    Set perm_dot = Nothing
End Sub
```

HTML:

Iframe Screenshot:
[image: Iframe Screenshot]

Element Screenshot:
[image: Element Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might because the script runs faster than the page load. You could add a wait before switch to the iframe. Besides, there might be other elements with name `iframe_Roundtrip_9223372036563636042` so you could use `FindElementById` when searching the iframe.

I made a simple sample with code below and it can work well:

```
Public Sub seleniumtutorial()
    Dim driver As New Selenium.IEDriver
    driver.Get "https://zhouyuzy.github.io/create-test-page/iframe.html  "
    driver.Wait 5000
    driver.SwitchToFrame driver.FindElementById("iframe_Roundtrip_9223372036563636042")
    driver.FindElementById("BUTTON_OPEN_SAVE_btn1_acButton").Click
    driver.Wait 5000
End Sub
```

The result is like below:

[image]